# It is not possible to add event in dynamic form?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

There are many example adding event handler for other object such as button, textbox, but there are not for Windows form.

I am trying to add an event handler to my Windows form, and I stuck in error

Here is my code

```
            Form f = new Form();
            f.BackColor = Color.White;
            f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            f.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            f.TopMost = true;
            f.Opacity = 0.6;
            f.Click = new EventHandler(this.FakeMouseEvent);

            f.Show();
```

Is there anyone help me out?

I wanna use mouseClick event in dynamic form.

Comment: Try: `f.Click += FakeMouseEvent`

Comment: The `Form` is just a UI element like every other control: `Button`, `Textbox`, etc.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Thx. After changing code from  f.Click = new EventHandler(this.FakeMouseEvent); to f.Click += FakeMouseEvent;, there is no error anymore

Comment: getting error because you are creating new EventHandler instead of MouseEventHandler. you can cast it to MouseEventHandler or create new MuoseEventHandler(function) or simply add it: form.event+=function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Forms events are standard .NET events, so you can append your handler like

```
 f.Click += FakeMouseEvent;
```

and also remove it like

```
 f.Click -= FakeMouseEvent;
```